# Compute mean and variance of $Y=\text{min}\{n:X_n=1,X_{n-1}=0\}.$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Let $X_1,X_2,...,X_n$ be a sequence of independent coin tosses, that
>   is $P(X=1)=P(X=0)=1/2.$
>
> **a)** Compute the mean and variance of
>   $Y=\text{min}\{n:X_n=1,X_{n-1}=0\}.$
>
> **b)** Compute the mean and variance of
>   $Y=\text{min}\{n:X_n=1=X_{n-1}=1\}.$

I don't even understand what I'm supposed to do here. What do they exactly mean by those min-functions? Where do I begin?

Any tips are welcome and explanations are welcome.

---

**EDIT:** After @gt6989b's post I've come to the following attempt.

**a)** The minimal $n$ for a sequence such as this is obtained by the sum of two random variables $Y=Z+W$. Both these random variables have a geometric distribution with parameter $p=1/2.$ So

$$E[Y]=E[Z+W]=E[Z]+E[W]=\frac{1}{p} + \frac{1}{p}=2+2 = 4.$$
$$\text{Var}[Y]=\text{Var}[Z+W]=\text{Var}[Z]+\text{Var}[W]=\frac{1-p}{p^2}+\frac{1-p}{p^2}=4.$$

**b)** For this part, finding the minimal $n$ such that two consecutive tosses show $11$ should be done in the same manner. But there still seems to be a fundamental difference between a) and b). In the problem statement, for part a) there is a comma between $X_n$ and $X_{n-1}$ but not in part b).

Can anyone explain the difference here?

Comment: You know how a geometric variable is the time you spend waiting if you flip a coin once per second until the result is heads? (a) is like that, except it is the time spent waiting for the consecutive pattern HT. (b) is the same, but for HH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Part (a) can be solved with some cleverness. The sequence of coin flips will begin with some run of $0$s (possibly empty), followed by some run of one more $1$s, followed by a $0$. That is,
$$
\underbrace{00\dots01}_N \,\underbrace{11\dots10}_M
$$
At this point, you are done, since $10$ has occured at the end, after $N+M$ flips. Note that $N$ and $M$ are independent geometric random variables with parameter $1/2$, so you can use their known means and variances to find that of $N+M$.

Part (b) is not so simple. The idea is this; you are waiting for $11$. If your first flip is $0$, then it is no help, so you are back to square zero. Same if your first two flips are $10$. If your first two flips are $11$, then the wait time is $2$. In summary, if $X$ is the wait time, then
$$
X=\begin{cases} 
X+1&\text{with probability }1/2\\
X+2&\text{with probability }1/4\\
2&\text{with probability }1/4
\end{cases}
$$
The $=$ should be viewed as an equality in distribution. Taking the expected value of both sides of that equation, you get
$$
EX=\frac12E(X+1)+\frac14E(X+2)+\frac14\cdot 2
$$
This equation can be solved for $E(X)$. To find the variance of $X$, use $\text{Var }X=E(X^2)-(EX)^2$, and solve for $E(X^2)$ using a similar method:
$$
E(X^2)=\frac12E[(X+1)^2]+\frac14E[(X+2)^2]+\frac14\cdot 2^2\tag 1
$$

**Edit:** Here is a different way to think about it. There are three states the game can be in; the initial state $S_0$, the state $S_1$ where you have already flipped a $1$ and are waiting for your second, and the state $S_2$ where you have seen $11$.

- If you are in state $S_0$, then flipping a $1$ moves you to $S_1$. However, flipping a $0$ leaves you in state $S_0$, since that $0$ is of no help to you. Letting $T_0$ be the expected wait time starting from state $S_0$, and $T_1$ be the expected wait time starting from $T_1$, this implies $$T_0=1+\frac12 T_0+\frac12 T_1\implies T_0 = 2+T_1$$
- If you are in state $S_1$, then flipping a $0$ erases all your progress, leaving you in state $S_0$. Flipping a $1$ means you immediately win. Therefore,
  $$
  T_1 = 1+\frac{1}2T_0
  $$

The last two equations can be solved for $T_0$ to get the expectation. However, to compute the variance, I see no way but to use $(1)$.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the wait time whre you summarise the different probabilites? I don't really follow that step. Why are there only three possibilities?

Comment: @Parseval see edit

Answer (score 1):

Consider a realized sequence $X_1, X_2, \ldots$ of such flips. For example, it could be $10001111000\ldots$.

The first place (minimal $n$) that you see a $0$ followed by a $1$ ($X_{n-1}=0,X_n=1$) is $n=5$. Part (a) asks what is the mean and variance of such first place over all possible random sequences.

Similarly, (b) asks the same for the sequence $11$.

Comment: Thank you! Please see my edit.